# Python - k fold cross validation for linear_model.Lasso

Tags: python, linear-regression, cross-validation

I have a following code using `linear_model.Lasso`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
clf = linear_model.Lasso()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

I want to perform k fold (10 times to be specific) cross_validation. What would be the right code to do that?

Answer (score 5):

here is the code I use to perform cross validation on a linear regression model and also to get the details:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_Train, Y_Train, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-scores)
```

As said in [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781491962282/) book at page 108 this is the reason why we use -score:

> Scikit-Learn cross-validation features expect a utility function
>   (greater is better) rather than a cost function (lower is better), so
>   the scoring function is actually the opposite of the MSE (i.e., a
>   negative value), which is why the preceding code computes -scores
>   before calculating the square root.

and to visualize the result use this simple function:

```
def display_scores(scores):
    print("Scores:", scores)
    print("Mean:", scores.mean())
    print("Standard deviation:", scores.std())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run 10-fold using the `model_selection` module:

```
# for 0.18 version or newer, use:
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

# for pre-0.18 versions of scikit, use:
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

X = # Some features
y = # Some classes

clf = linear_model.Lasso()
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10)
```

This code will return 10 different scores. You can easily get the mean:

```
scores.mean()
```

Comment: I'm using Python3, and I got the following error message: ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.model_selection'. Any clues?

Comment: Which scikit-learn version are you using? The model_selection module functionality used to be in cross_validation module

Comment: I'm using '0.17.1'

Comment: In that case, you need to import sklean.cross_validation.
I am updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry... I was able to import the module, however, when I run the rest, I got the following error message: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'

Comment: In fact, initialization of a `KFold` instance is not required, since this is the default method. It can be replaced by `10` instead.